# Creating a category page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have built a photo sharing application that enables users to sign up and post photos. But all of those pictures end up on the home page. Instead I want people to choose different categories to post their pictures depending what it is about. So I decided to make a categories html page with buttons that redirects you to the category shown below.

[image]

So I made the html page and added buttons and this is where I pretty much am clueless on what to do next. If anyone can help me that would totally mean a lot to me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Having an extra column like `photo_type` in your photos table would help you in dealing with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to assign a single `category` to a single `photo`, you'll need to use an [ActiveRecord Association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) -

```
#app/models/photo.rb
Class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category #-> needs category_id in users table
end

#app/models/category.rb
Class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :photos
end
```

Schemas:

```
photos
id | category_id | etc | created_at | updated_at

categories
id | name | created_at | updated_at
```

This will allow you to do this:

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "categories#index"
resources :categories

#app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
def index
    @categories = Category.all
end

def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
end

#app/views/categories/index.html.erb
<% for category in @categories do %>
    <%= link_to category.name, category %>
<% end %>

#app/views/categories/show.html.erb
<% for photo in @category.photos do %>
    <%= image_tag photo %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I already have a root, and it won't allow me to add another root.

Comment: Don't need one - just browse to `domain.com/categories` to show the categories index

Comment: can I shoot you an email or something if its fine with you? this is very frustrating, its probably best if you take a first look at it.

Comment: sure - rich@frontlinepcutilities.com

Comment: Just sent you an email, thanks for investing your time.